# Eclipse indexing takes forever

Tags: eclipse, performance, jsp, indexing, cpu-usage

I have Eclipse Helios SR1 installed on my Ubuntu 10.04 desktop and I'm having to work with a huge set of web projects in it.

When I import the projects eclipse builds the workspace successfully but it keeps consuming 100% of the CPU invariably.

After checking what could be happening I found that in Eclipse's progress tab there is a couple of endless tasks:

- System: Java indexing... n files to index
- System: Updating JSP index
- System: Persisting JSP translations

These tasks seem to never end and makes my Eclipse unusable.

I doubt it is a memory issue, I have 2GB in this machine and Eclipse's heap size does not get greater than 350MB and Xmx is set currently to 1024MB.

Also tried running Eclipse with different VM versions: Sun's 1.6, Sun's 1.5, and Open JDK 1.6. No changes.

I have an Athlon X2 2.2GHz processor and a 7200 rpm Samsung hard drive.

The source code is shared via SVN.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be going on?

This is my eclipse.ini just in case:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here are my baseline eclipse vmargs suggestions: You seem to be on 32 bit, so I advise -server (eclipse is a long running app which can benefit from more thorough JIT).    You have left your garbage collector unspecified, so at the very least use -XX:+UseParallelOldGC.  You may prefer -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC as it ought to improve interactivity.

Answer (score 6):

To fix this problem, you have to close Eclipse, delete everything in the folder:

```
<workspace>.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2
```

and restart again.

And then wait a couple of mitutes for the reindexing.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 10.10 with the SpringSource Tool Suite 2.5.2. This has been reported as [Bug 321602](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321602#c10).

Just download attachment 180339 and patch your Eclipse.

The official patch will be released in SR2 around end February 2011.

Answer (score 0):

in workspace .metadata - > .plugins -> org.eclipse.jst.jsp

just remove above folder in .plugins

no matter eclipse is open or not

gives instant results